# RewriteRule Didn't Work for Me

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, web

My navigation is `example.com/admin/?nav=home` and I want RewriteRule to show only `example.com/admin/` or `example.com/admin/home` or `example.com/admin/new`.

I tried some tutorials but they didn't work. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Can you post your Rewrite code?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /?nav=$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./?nav=$1 [R]` but i tried lots of codes from tutorials and didnt work :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On     
RewriteBase /               
RewriteRule ^admin/home$    admin/?nav=home
```

This will show `admin/?nav=home` as `/admin/home`

For dynamic URLs try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)$ /admin/?nav=$1 [L]
```

Comment: +1, nice and clean... Maybe remove the `/` in front of `admin` on the dynamic portion :)

Comment: @Lizardor Maybe you removed the `RewriteBase`? Also do you have other rules that might conflict (before or after)?

Comment: @zx81 i tried remove RewriteBase nothing, yes i have some other rules after

Comment: @Lizardor can you post your .htaccess file please?

Comment: @zx81 but it didnt work same, when i delete other rules(its rules set by webhosting)

Comment: hmm, it may be problem ... you can try my solution here: [htaccess.madewithlove.be](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be) ... it's working for me